# React-router-dom 6: Reload page once with 'render' seems not to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml-parsing, react-router-dom

I built an App with `react-router-dom@6` and I'm facing the issue that the content isn't displayed first time. I have to refresh manually to see the content.
I tried to use `export class App() extends React.Component {...}` and wrap the return statement by `render() { return (...)}`, like shown in many examples in the web.
Unfortunately I still need to do a refresh.
Could give anybody me a hint?

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'; 
...
export class App extends React.Component    {
    
    sessionStorage.setItem('xmlString', xmlString);
    sessionStorage.setItem('xmlUnitData', xmlUnitData);
    sessionStorage.setItem('googleApiKey', googleApiKey);

    render() {
        return (
            <MainDataContext.Provider value={{ allUnitData: GetAllUnitData() }}>
                <Router>
                    <MainHeader />
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                          ...
                        <Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
                    </Routes>
                </Router>
            </MainDataContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: This might be *too* minimal a [mcve]. It's not clear what would cause any issue. Are the `sessionStorage.setItem` calls unintentional side-effects? What route are you trying to access?

Comment: The `sessionStorage.setItem` works fine I think. I can also move these calls outside of the App 'function' and still have the same issue.
The issue I have is:
If call my App in a new browser session I see simply nothing. Only if I reload the complete page (e.g. by F5) then it works like expected.

Comment: What content are you referring to that isn't loading/render/whatever on the initial render? Let's start with that. Can you provide a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: Will do so, takes a little bit time.

Comment: I simplyfied my app and now it works with the first browser request.
The must be another reason. I think I have to dive deeper in the code.

Comment: Issue is fixed now. There was an XMLParser Error behind the scenes. Now I'm checking if this error occoures and this this case I reload the page.

Comment: `const xmlUnitData = xmlParser.parseFromString(sessionStorage.xmlUnitData,"text/xml");

if ( xmlUnitData.querySelector('parsererror') ) {
 window.location.reload();
}`